# Meaning of 'alzar', 'avolto' and 'pareano' here?

Tags: translation, history

In Tasso's Gerusalemme Liberata, Canto Primo, Octave 58 we see:

> ```
>   Ma il fanciullo Rinaldo, e sovra questi 
>   e sovra quanti in mostra eran condutti,
>   dolcemente feroce alzar vedresti
>   la regal fronte, e in lui mirar sol tutti.
>   L'età precorse e la speranza, e presti
>   pareano i fior quando n'usciro i frutti;
>   se 'l miri fulminar ne l'arme avolto,
>   Marte lo stimi; Amor, se scopre il volto.
> ```

I know Spanish, French and some Latin good enough to deduce the meaning of most of words here, but those from the title still remain a mystery for me. I take it ***alzar*** here might be a relative of *alzare* and mean something like 'ampiezza', but could this be a noun as well? Or a shortened form of the verb?

What is ***avolto***? A participle, an ajective, or a noun?

And, last but not least, what is ***pareano***? Does it stand for 'similar to' (like French pareil) or something different?

Comment: I would like to note that I don't understand where ancient-Italian and poetry related questions fall into the scope of this SE. Modern Italian is different from ancient Italian, that's all (the same happens for Greek language)

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ See 'language history' and 'cause and effect'. Both modern languages derive from their ancestors, so it doesn't matter whether the topics concern their modern Italian or old Italian (and it's not 'ancient', it's just 'auld', because 'Ancient Italian' means 'Latin'), Ancient Greek or Modern Greek.

Answer (score 7):

*Alzar* is the verb "alzare" (with the elision of the last vowel) = to raise, to lift up, to grow.

*Avolto* seems a poetic form for "avvolto" (past participle) (here the same verses have "avvolto" https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Gerusalemme_liberata/Canto_primo) = wrapped.

*Pareano* is a poetic form for for "parevano" = they seemed, they looked like.